# Book set in a time of dragons featuring a boy and his dragon saving their homeland from weird monsters

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons, fairy

I have been trying to remember the title of a book I read like a year ago. It is based in a time of dragons and the two main characters in the book is a boy and a dragon. The boy and dragon are friends, and they have to try to save their homeland from weird monsters. There are also dwarves and other dragons. What is the title of this book? I think the book started with an E.

Comment: Were there fairies involved, then?

Comment: There were elves and elves are part of the fairy race.

Comment: This isn't much to go on. Please look at our [guide to asking a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any other details you can remember.

Comment: This is all I can remember about the story.

Comment: Even if you think that's all you remember, I recommend visiting that list of prompts Null linked. Even something as simple as whether you remember it as a paperback or hardback, or what reading level it was, can help us a lot to clarify the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might you be thinking on *[Eragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon)*?

> A Shade named Durza, along with a group of Urgals, ambushes a party of three elves. They kill two of them, and Durza attempts to steal an egg carried by the remaining female elf, but she uses magic to teleport it elsewhere. Infuriated, he abducts her.
>
> Eragon is a fifteen-year-old boy who has lived with his uncle Garrow and cousin Roran on a farm near the village of Carvahall, left there by his mother Selena after his birth. While hunting, the dragon egg appears in front of him. The night after, a baby dragon hatches from the egg, and bonds with Eragon. Eragon names the dragon Saphira, after a name the old village storyteller Brom mentions.
>
> He raises the dragon in secret until two of King Galbatorix's servants, the Ra'zac, come to Carvahall. Eragon and Saphira escape and hide in the Spine, but Garrow is fatally wounded and the farm is burned down by the Ra'zac. Once Garrow dies, Eragon and Saphira decide to hunt the Ra'zac, in vengeance. Brom insists on accompanying him and Saphira, and gives Eragon the sword Zar'roc.

It involves a boy, his dragon, elves, and weird monsters, and the title starts with an E.

Comment: That is the story thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm going to mark this question as a Duplicate, but please note that this does not mean it's a bad question, simply that it's been asked before, and we like to link them in the system. I hope you stick around. We're a fun site.

Comment: I plan on sticking around.